# is using has_and_belongs_to_many for models is a bad idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Can some one please explain the the pros and cons between has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing bad about using habtm per se. The reason why many people don't use this kind of association is that they use has_many :through instead. Why? Because it's more versatile. While HABTM "hides" the intermediary table, when using has_many :through the middle man is a resource by itself - which is usually a good thing (if for nothing, you can timestamp the relationship). You'll come across many situations when you'll need to add some behavior or attributes to such a relationship (when designing a system in a resource-oriented fashion).

Comment: I'm starting to see the significance of this myself... the added flexibilty really is beneficial as specifications change. Curious, though: if I had a habtm relationship between Users and Meals, but I now need the intermediary table, what would I call the intermediary table? Is it a whole new resource called meal_user or something?

Comment: I realize that this is an older question, but usually you'd call it something to do with the other attributes and the purpose for storing them, as it is now a new resource.

For instance, if it were a meal rating out of 5, that might comprise the "rating" resource.