# Creating intermediate model for has and belongs to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation between two models.

```
class DirectoryListing 
 has_and_belongs_to_many :directory_listing_categories

end

class DirectoryListingCategory
 has_and_belongs_to_many :directory_listings

end
```

This created two tables `directory_listings` and `directory_listing_categories`

and an intermediate third table named
`directory_listing_categories_directory_listings`

I can access the first two tables from console using active record query.
Since this relation won't create a third model for the intermediate third table, I cant access the third intermediate table from rails console.

I tried creating a model for that, but not been successful.

Is this right way to access the third table?

```
class DirectoryListingCategoryDirectoryListing < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Comment: If you want to have 'intermediate model', why don't you use `has_many :through` instead `has_and_belongs_to_many`?

Comment: I forgot to mention this is a live code. I am not supposed change that association.

Comment: You have no way to access intermediate model with `has_and_belongs_to_many`, it's how the association works. If you want to do something with intermediate model you have to change association `has_many :through`, there is no other ways

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a small app where I had to store some roles and map them to users. The setup was:

1. `User` model corresponds to `users` table.
2. `Role` model corresponds to `roles` table.
3. I needed a table to do the many-to-many mapping.

The migration that I wrote to create the association table was something like this:

```
class CreateUserRoleJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    create_join_table :users, :roles
  end

  def down
    drop_join_table :users, :roles
  end
end
```

When you run the migration, Rails created a `roles_users`. If you want, you can also add foreign_keys and unique indexes in the `up` method.

The models are like:

#### User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end
```

#### Role

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

---

So it is more or less the same kind of setup.

This setup gives me the following methods on User object (represented by the `user` object below:

1. **`user.role_ids`**: This will *fetch* me the role IDs of the roles this user is associated with.
2. **`user.role_ids=`**: This will allow me to set Roles with users using both assignment and array insertion. Like so:

   ```
   user.role_ids = 1 # Assuming there are no roles already associated with the user
   user.role_ids = [2,6] # This will remove the previously assigned role (with ID = 1) and assign the roles with IDs 2 & 6 to the user
   user.role_ids << 5 # This will add the role ID 5 to the user (final role_ids at this point will be [2,5,6]
   ```
3. **`user.roles`**: This is similar to `user.role_ids` but will fetch me the Role objects instead of IDs.
4. **`user.roles=`**: Again, similar to `user.role_ids=` but will take objects instead of IDs.

Similarly for the Role model, I get `role.user_ids`, `role.user_ids=`, `role.users`, `role.users=`.

The point is - I rarely, if ever need to touch the `roles_users` table.

If I do, I can do a **`User.connection.execute(sql)`** and manually read the results. Otherwise, the automatically injected methods will suffice.

I hope this helped.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, to access the table in the console, there must be a model created in the app with the same name as the table.

Secondly, if you want to create a record of the intermediate table then you should create it by executing raw query in the console by,

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('your insert into query goes here')
```

Comment: No, you should definitely not write a raw query

Comment: @idmean Then why don't they deprecate this method? Actually, in some cases, your query will be modified according to the needs/data or any other conditions, so at that time you can simply modify the query and execute it. you might not be faced with such scenarios so you don't know it.

Comment: ActiveRecord is capable of expressing most of the queries you'll write. If you need additional data in your join table, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857730/is-using-has-and-belongs-to-many-for-models-is-a-bad-idea. There's cases where ActiveRecord cannot help you, such as recursive CTE's, that's why `connection.execute` cannot be deprecated. But this doesn't mean you should use it for things that can be achieved through cleaner interfaces